# Addition Function Parameter Location in Assembly Stack Memory

Tags: disassembly

So my C program looks like:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 5;
    int b = 1;
    int c = add(a, b);
    printf("%d", c);
    return 0;
}

int add(int a, int b){
    return a + b;
}
```

And I am trying to understand the behaviour of how parameters are passed into the stack. In order to do the same, I reversed the code to disassembly:

[image]

[image: main_function]

Now `esp` is being copied into `ebp` in the `add` function, then why add `8` and `12` to access the values `5` and `1` in the next lines - shouldn't it be `[ebp]` and `[ebp + 4h]`? I am really confused here.

Thanks.

Comment: "I am not posting it in the Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange site." and then you proceed doing just that :)

Comment: Probably a stackexchange-nazi-purist closed its question... In these days every question get downvoted..

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Opps, I just thought I was gonna post it at SO and realized it will get way too many negative votes. The artefact remained - cleaned it now~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On x86, the stack is used *not only* for passing the arguments. It can store other things as well, for example the return address of the function or the registers which need to be saved temporarily, as well as for local variables. In your example, the `push ebp` adjusts `esp` by 4 bytes, so after `esp` is copied to `ebp` in the next instruction, the stack frame looks like this:

```
 [ebp+0] old ebp value (pushed by "push ebp")
 [ebp+4] return address from the call (originally at [esp+0])
 [ebp+8] first argument (a)
 [ebp+C] second argument (b)
```

Comment: +1 for a clear and easy to grasp answer!

Answer (score 2):

ebp is an address     likewise esp ia an address like  0x12345678

esp is not copied

it is assigned so after mov ebp,esp
both will be same address

in high level language it would be like  ebp = esp

now since ebp is an address it can hold a value

that is  ebp can hold 0x12345678  ( ebp ,xxx is a pointer to the underlying data )

so ebp = 0x12345678  a pointer points to data 0x12345678 a data variable  ( like your 5 and 1 )

ebp          12345678  holds 1
ebp +4     1234567c holds  x
evp+8      12345680 holds y

since ebp and esp are same  esp+8 will also be holding y

this part is called prologue   in the function construct 
and creates a frame  in the stack

the square brackets denotes  access to the underlying data

so if you want to access ebp +c     you may need

mov somereg  ebp 
add samereg   0xc
now this register will hold 0x12345680

what if you want to access  y

the you need the square bracket around  ox12345680

like  get me what is dereferenced by  [0x12345680]

that is  mov somereg  [ebp + c]